# Standard accounts are able to get root access using sudo without password request

Tags: password, sudo, root, permissions

I installed some software by running its install script with

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

After the installation all the accounts on my Ubuntu laptop can gain root access by simply issuing the command `sudo -s`, even the standard (non administrator) account. Also there is no password prompt when issuing the command `sudo -s`.

My `/etc/sudoers` looks like this:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Open the install script in text editor. See what it was doing with `/etc/sudoers` and revert them.

Comment: This may have been done by that "particular software" you mentioned. Unless they warned you that this will happen you should file this as a bug against the software.

Comment: Include in your question the content of /etc/sudoers.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rf1WuHB0
My sudoers file

Comment: Can we also get a link to where you got the script please?

Comment: It's a serious security bug for any software's installation script to add a line like `ALL ALL=(ALL)` to a sudoers file. So if possible, please do let us know where you got the installation script (as @Rinzwind says) and/or what software the script came with or is for, so that the bug can be reported to its developers and hopefully fixed quickly. Thanks!

Comment: sooo, what was this software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the very bottom of your sudoers file, it says "ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL". This is the syntax for passwordless execution of sudo. Make a backup of the file and then delete that line.

Andrew

Comment: But why does non adminstrator accounts can also sudo to the root ?

Comment: The line says "ALL", indicating all users.

Answer (score 4):

Remove this line:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But this is REALLY strange to appear, so the software (basically a script I guess) you installed is probably mallicious. You might want to start a second question, paste the contents of that script there, and ask for advice... this is scary!

Comment: But why does non adminstrator accounts can also sudo to the root ?

Comment: Because that's exactly what that line says? `ALL` is the keyword here. The line starting with `%admin` says that all members of group admin have sudo rights, and this line says that everyone has it.