# Why don't the commands 'sudo bash' or 'sudo -s' ask for a password?

Tags: command-line, bash, password, sudo, root

Even when I am logged in as a non-admin user, when I enter `sudo bash` or `sudo -s`, the system does not ask for any password. In the command history, I have not entered any password for `sudo` earlier (i.e., `sudo` did not cache any user credentials which might cause it to not ask for my password again in this session.)

Why is this strange behavior?
And how do I make sure that every `sudo` and `su` command requires a corresponding password? And how to strictly ensure that any user cannot get root privileges without entering the root password?

Here is the content of my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: possible dup of either [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/139723/184942), [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/316256/184942) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/349348/184942).

Comment: Can you paste contents of `/etc/sudoers` file to pastebin.ubuntu.com and post the link to your question? Also what is the output of `ls /etc/sudoers.d`?

Comment: here is sudoers http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7107623/ and /etc/sudoers.d does not have any files except README

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the last line of your `/etc/sudoers` file, which states:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

...meaning "all users can execute all commands as root without any password".

I don't know how that line got in there, but if you remove it you will restore the normal behavior. **Note:** use `visudo` for editing to make sure you don't get any syntax errors in there, i.e., execute the command

```
sudo visudo
```

and edit the file using the editor that pops up.